# When is a connection timedout exception thrown in java?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

This is my code :

```
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(to_be_sent);
out.flush();
out.close();
int resp_code=connection.getResponseCode();
if(resp_code==200)
{
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(obj.frame, "Your Application has been sent Successfully");
}
```

As you can see I have set the connection timeout to be 5 seconds. I want to know when this connection time exception is thrown and which line throws it. Is it thrown when connection.getResponseCode() does not return anything for 5 seconds?

**Edit**
Looked up javadocs just now and found out that getResponse code only throws `IOException` when not able to connect to the server.

Comment: You left out the part of the connection. Is it a urlconnection or one of its sub wrappers? Such as Http or Https UrlConnection?

Comment: according to documentation of setConnectTimeout() "when opening a communications link to the resource referenced by this URLConnection. If the timeout expires before the connection can be established, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the connection and connecting are a multi-step process, some of the parameters won't have any effect after performing the connection.

Assuming you are using URLConnection, if you already called connect(), or one of the methods that implicitly perform the connection, it would have no effect at all.

If the connection was made implicitly with getOutputStream method, the exception will be thrown at your second line of code

This throws java.net.SocketTimeoutException if the connection cannot be made in the specified time.
More info about the connect method and setting the connection parameters [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29)

Comment: :according to documentation of setConnectTimeout() "when opening a communications link to the resource referenced by this URLConnection. If the timeout expires before the connection can be established, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised". I am not using connect() so the connection only takes place when I wirte some thing in the outputstream. So the timeout period will start only after write something in the outputstream right? Otherwise it does not make any sense.

Comment: Getting the outputStream will open the connection implicitly, from the javadoc: _Operations that depend on being connected, like getContentLength, will implicitly perform the connection, if necessary._ I have updated the answer to refer this

Comment: right, so the time-out countdown only starts after outputstream is opened and not after I call connection.setConnectTimeout(5000)?

Comment: That's right, you could do several time-consuming operations between setting the parameter and opening the connection, and you won't get the timeout

Comment: That's a different problem, it means the URL you specified is not parseable, the client is not even trying to attempt the connection... Does your URL has the protocol, correct slashes, etc??

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know when this connection time exception is thrown and which line throws it.

I think it will occur in the statement that opens the output stream.

However, the best answer is to try it yourself and see.  Put a try/catch around the whole thing, attempt to connect to a URL that is going to timeout, and then examine the stacktrace to see where the timeout exception came from.

---

> Looked up javadocs just now and found out that `getResponseCode()` only throws `IOException` when not able to connect to the server.

That may be true (... I'm not entirely convinced ...) but this does not mean that the exception won't be thrown before then.  And if you think about it, it *pretty much has to* happen before then.  You can't write and flush data to the server if you haven't established the connection yet!

---

Eugenio's answer is correct too.  You have to call `setConnectTimeout(...)` before the connection attempt is made.  If you set it afterwards, the timeout has no effect.

---

> So here is my actual problem. I want to tell the user that he is not connected to the internet. For that I gave the `connectTimeout()`. But instead of throwing a timeout exception, it is throwing `MalformedURLException`.

Presumably that is happening because it cannot do a DNS lookup to resolve the hostname in the URL.  Alternatively (and IMO more likely), this exception is being thrown because the URL is malformed ... and that's a different problem entirely.  And you DO NOT want to tell the user that the internet is down if the *real* problem is that someone has entered an incorrect URL!!

If you want to test that you have internet connectivity, you will need to do things that are lower level ... as it were; e.g.

- attempt to open a socket connection to the host whose IP address you already know,
- try to use `InetAddress.getByName()` to resolve a known DNS name, or
- use the `NetworkInterface` class to see if the local machine has "live" network interfaces.

In reality, determining that "the internet is working" is rather hard to do, when you consider all of the possible things that can go wrong to prevent effective internet access.

Comment: Stephen C : okay.. thanks:) I will try the InetAddress.getByName().

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know when this connection time exception is thrown

It is thrown when the attempt to connect times out.

> and which line throws it.

The stack trace tells you which line throws it.